# Jumping with gravity & collision

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm trying to make a simple platformer in love2D. Currently I've got my player class down among other stuff (collision handling class, level classes etc)

The main problem I'm having is jumping. I just can't get it to work properly.

When I jump, the player gets pulled back down too fast to actually make the jump useful. Why is this happening? This is code ported over from ROBLOX, and in ROBLOX Studio, the jumping works normally.

This is inside the player's update function which is called every frame from love.update:

```
if not love.keyboard.isDown("a") and not love.keyboard.isDown("d") then 
    self.Velocity=self.Velocity * Vector2.new(0.95,1)
end
if self.Velocity.Y < -self.maxFallVel then
    self.Velocity=Vector2.new(self.Velocity.X,self.maxFallVel)
end
if love.keyboard.isDown("d") and self.Velocity.X<self.maxVel and not love.keyboard.isDown("a") then
    self.Velocity = self.Velocity+Vector2.new(.1,0) -- right movement
end
if love.keyboard.isDown("a") and self.Velocity.X<self.maxVel and not love.keyboard.isDown("d") then
    self.Velocity = self.Velocity-Vector2.new(.1,0) -- left movement
end
if love.keyboard.isDown("space") and self.hasCollision and not self.Jumped then
    if self.Velocity.Y == 0 then
        self.Velocity.Y = -30 
    end
end
self.Position=self.Position+Vector2.new(self.Velocity.X,self.Velocity.Y)
if not self.hasCollision then self.Velocity.Y = self.Velocity.Y - self.Gravity end
```

When I check for collisions inside the main.lua file, that's where I set the variable self.hasCollision to true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if self.Velocity.Y < -self.maxFallVel then
    self.Velocity=Vector2.new(self.Velocity.X, -self.maxFallVel)  -- minus!
end
...
-- multiply by dt
self.Position=self.Position+Vector2.new(self.Velocity.X,self.Velocity.Y)*dt
if not self.hasCollision then 
  self.Velocity.Y = self.Velocity.Y - self.Gravity*dt   
end
```